# Show block on specific views search result

Tags: blocks

My view exposed search results path looks like this:

www.xyz.com/?field_port_tid=5971&field_length_value=&field_length_value_1=&field_cabins_value=&field_cabins_value_1=&field_price_week_range_value=&field_price_week_range_to_value=

I would like a block to show only if the path has specific taxonomy term in it (in this case tid=5971).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the **PHP filter** (not advised but still popular) module enabled you can use the *Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)* option for block visibility with the following code.

```
<?php return (isset($_GET['tid']) && $_GET['tid'] == 5971); ?>
```

Comment: I enabled the module and copy/pasted your code. It does not show up.

Comment: @BigBrother2010 That'll just be an example - replace `tid` with the parameter name you're interested in (`field_port_tid` probably)

Comment: Probably a caching issue. Have you checked that?

Comment: Just had to replace tid like @Clive said. Cheers.

Comment: Just a side question to Shawns answer. I read everywhere that PHP filter module is not advised. How unsecure is it to have it enabled if only me (admin) has access to it ?

Comment: Assuming there are no security holes found in Drupal (or any of the modules you have installed) that would allow an attacker to submit a form with the filter enabled, you're fine. It's always a risk though, look what happened with Drupalgeddon (not related to this of course, but it was a major flaw that no one knew about for years, who's to say there aren't others?)